# why can not I access the vector cars?

Tags: c++

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;
struct multa{
  int data;
};
struct veiculos{
  string placa;
 vector<multa*> multas;
};
int tam = 0;
vector<veiculos*> carros;
void insereVeiculos(){
    veiculos  *carrosparaadd = new veiculos;
    cout << "digite a placa do veiculo:" << endl;
    cin >> carrosparaadd->placa;
    carros.push_back(carrosparaadd);
    cout << carros[].placa;
    tam++;
   }
void inseremultas(){
   int cont = 0 ,i = 0;
   cout << "Quantas multas você quer adicionar?" << endl;
   cin >> cont;
   for(i=0;i<cont;i++){
     multa *multasparaadd = new multa;
     cout << "Digite a data da multa para add:" << endl;
     cin >> (*multasparaadd).data;
     cout << (*multasparaadd).data;
     carros[0]->multas.push_back(multasparaadd);
    }
}
```

why can not I access the vector cars? 
with carros[0].placa?I tested it and saw that it is getting the right value from the keyboard
Thanks.

Comment: what error are you getting?

Comment: Please translate the variable names into English so that the code is easier to understand / keep track of.

Comment: `carros[].placa;` you seem to be missing an index here (in the [])

Comment: carros[index].placa is also incorrect. carros[index] is veiculos* type. so carros[index]->placa is correct.

Comment: @Borgleader, that should be an answer.

Comment: If you do not speak english there is SO Espanol.

Answer (score 1):

Your expression

```cpp
cout << carros[].placa;
```

lacks an index for the array access and since it's a vector of pointers you also need to dereference the accessed element. A correct expression which compiles is for example:

```cpp
cout << carros[0]->placa;
```

If you want to print the element you just inserted, you can use either:

```cpp
cout << carros.back()->placa;
```

or, since you're inserting a pointer, simply:

```cpp
cout << carrosparaadd->placa;
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, really. Sorry my bad english.Now a have another problem. When i tried to delete the pointers *carrosparaadd and *multasparaadd it crashed...Do you know why?

Comment: You'll have to show the code that you're using to delete these pointers. Also, that sounds unrelated, so I would suggest accepting/closing this one and posing it in a new question.